# Best way to create a session cookie if it's not present and persist to a database using axum and tower_cookies?

Tags: rust, cookies, middleware, rust-axum

I'm relatively new to [`axum`](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/) and I'm trying to use it as the webserver for a service I'm creating.

I have some state which contains a database I would like to write session / session metadata to.

I want all users which access any route to set a session cookie if it's not already present in the header. I then want to write this session cookie to the database (which is stored in some state).

I am using the [`tower_cookies`](https://docs.rs/tower-cookies/latest/tower_cookies/) crate in an attempt to make cookie reading and writing more ergonomic, so I'd prefer if the middleware were able to access the `Cookies` struct rather than reading and writing the raw `Request<...>` and `Response<...>`.

All my attempts to do this have been insufficient in some fashion -- either being a standalone handler (instead of a middleware automatically applied to all routes), or not using the `Cookie` class (and dealing with the raw `Cookie` / `Set-Cookie` headers directly), or something similarly not ergonomic. I feel that this is a common thing to want to do so I must be missing something. For a distilled example of one of these not-ergonomic but compiling approaches:

```
// Problem: not using Cookies from the CookieManager, instead dealing with the headers directly.
pub async fn set_and_store_cookie_if_absent<B>(
    State(state): State<MyState>,
    request: Request<B>,
    next: Next<B>,
) -> Response {
    // Read request cookies, create / write new session to state.db if needed
    let response = next.run(request).await;
    // Write to response cookies.
    response
}

let state = MyState::new();
Route(...)
    .layer(
        ServiceBuilder::new()
            .layer(CookieManagerLayer::new())
            .layer(middleware::from_fn_with_state(state.clone(), set_and_store_cookie_if_absent)));
```

But this isn't using the `CookieManagerLayer` that I want to use.

Comment: You might be interested in [`tower-sessions`](https://github.com/maxcountryman/tower-sessions), which wraps `tower-cookies` to provide sessions. Full disclosure, I'm the author of the crate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, after doing some research, some of my attempted approaches were correct, except my `State` was wrapping a type that doesn't play well with async: https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/discussions/964#discussioncomment-2629585

So the right thing to do would be something like this:

```
pub async fn set_and_store_cookie_if_absent<B>(
    State(state): State<MyState>,
    cookies: Cookies,
    request: Request<B>,
    next: Next<B>,
) -> Response {
    if cookies.get(SESSION_COOKIE).is_none() {
        // handle, write to State, etc.
    }
    
    next.run(request).await
}
```

But this was giving me a TON of errors that were hard to wade through before -- because I was using `rusqlite` instead of something like `deadpool-sqlite`.